# End of UITextView text in Swift

Tags: swift, uiscrollview, uitextview

I am trying to detect when the user reaches a certain point in a text : String inside a UITextView. I am using `scrollViewDidEndDragging` but the result is not ideal. When I finish scrolling I still need to scroll further to make it happen. Also , when the text is only 1 page long, this method is never called. Is there a better way to known when the last line (or any other line) is visible to the screen ? 
Thank you

```
func scrollViewDidEndDragging(scrollView: UIScrollView, willDecelerate decelerate: Bool) {
        let bottomEdge: CGFloat = textField.contentOffset.y + textField.frame.size.height
        if (bottomEdge >= scrollView.contentSize.height) {
            //do stuff
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a naive solution which gets the substring's rect and checks whether that rect is visible.

The main drawback with this implementation is that it only works if your substring is unique (because it only grabs the first occurrence). But that shouldn't be too bad to implement (perhaps with an array of rects that you check).

**UITextView Helpers**

I've created an extension on `UITextView` for convenience. It provides two methods: One for determining the rect of a substring and another for checking whether that rect is visible.

`rectForText` is quite verbose mainly because of the conversion of `Range<Index>` into `UITextRange` which proved to be more painful than expected. If anyone knows of an easier way please share.

```
extension UITextView {
    func rectForText(targetText: String) -> CGRect? {
        if let range = text.rangeOfString(targetText) {
            let beginning = beginningOfDocument
            let startOffset = text.startIndex.distanceTo(range.startIndex)
            if let start = positionFromPosition(beginning, offset: startOffset) {
                let endOffset = text.startIndex.distanceTo(range.endIndex) - startOffset
                if let end = positionFromPosition(start, offset: endOffset) {
                    if let textRange = textRangeFromPosition(start, toPosition: end) {
                        return firstRectForRange(textRange)
                    }
                }
            }
        }

        return nil
    }

    func isRectVisible(rect: CGRect?) -> Bool {
        if let rect = rect {
            return CGRectIntersectsRect(rect, bounds)
        }

        return false
    }
}
```

**Test Code**

Finally I've created a simple test project which has a view controller with a single text view. Notice that it checks for visibility once when the view appears and then continuously as the scroll view scrolls. I've also cached the test rect to avoid recomputing it each time you scroll. But if you text is dynamic then you'll have to recompute this.

```
class ViewController: UIViewController, UITextViewDelegate {
    @IBOutlet weak var myTextView: UITextView!
    var rectOfString: CGRect?

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        myTextView.delegate = self
        myTextView.text = "foo bar foo bar foo bar foo bar foo bar foo bar foo bar foo bar foo bar foo bar foo bar foo bar foo bar foo bar foo bar foo bar foo bar foo bar foo bar foo bar foo bar foo bar foo bar foo bar foo bar foo bar foo bar foo bar foo bar foo bar foo bar foo bar foo bar foo bar foo bar foo bar foo bar foo bar foo bar foo bar foo bar foo bar foo bar foo bar foo bar My cool substring foo bar foo bar foo bar foo bar foo bar foo bar foo bar foo bar foo bar foo bar foo bar "
        rectOfString = myTextView.rectForText("My cool substring")
    }

    override func viewDidAppear(animated: Bool) {
        super.viewDidAppear(animated)

        checkTextVisibility()
    }

    private func checkTextVisibility() {
        if myTextView.isRectVisible(rectOfString) {
            print("Visible :)")
        } else {
            print("Not visible :(")
        }
    }
}

extension ViewController: UIScrollViewDelegate {
    func scrollViewDidScroll(scrollView: UIScrollView) {
        checkTextVisibility()
    }
}
```

Comment: @PoolHallJunkie Hey, you're right my answer wasn't complete. I've completely rewritten my answer with a solution that I've now tested. Hopefully this is a better solution.